# Simulación de algoritmo de fuerza bruta java

Tags: java

muy buenas comunidad tengo el siguiente problema ...
debo simular un algoritmo de fuerza bruta que me ayude a descifrar una cadena de 5 caracteres ingresada por el usuario, el algoritmo debe mostrar todas las combinaciones realizadas hasta descifrar la cadena
el problema está en que no entiendo bien que debo hacer ... tengo el siguiente código de momento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon el código como texto, no como imagen, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que has hecho

Comment: Lo que hace un algoritmo de fuerza bruta es, como su propio nombre indica, ir probando todas las combinaciones disponibles existentes. En tu caso, como es de tamaño 5, lo que debe hacer es, empezar con "aaaaa" y luego ir modificando cada valor de la cadena sustituyendo el valor de la iteración por otra letra. Ejemplo, "aaaaa", "aaaab", "aaaac", ... , "azsde", etc. Y así, hasta que llegue el momento que la contraseña coincida.

Comment: Muchas gracias estimados, he estado algo ocupado sin embargo parece que ya le di solición, mañana sin falta subo el código les agradezco mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás esto te sirva:

```
package Ejercicios;
import java.util.*;
public class Prueba {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String cadena;
        int cantidad_maxima_de_caracteres = 255;
        StringBuilder respuesta = new StringBuilder();
        int longitud = 0;
        System.out.println("Ingrese la cadena:");
        cadena=sc.next();
        while(true){
            if(cadena.equals(respuesta) || longitud >= cadena.length())
                break;
            for(int i = 0; i <= cantidad_maxima_de_caracteres; i++){
                char caracter_de_contrasenia = cadena.charAt(longitud);
                char caracter_a_chequear = (char) i;
                if(caracter_de_contrasenia == caracter_a_chequear){
                    //Puedes escoger entre agregar el caracter que está en la contraseña o el que estás chequeando (al entrar aquí significa que coincide):
                    //Agregando el caracter que está en la contraseña (otra opción es: respuesta.append(caracter_a_chequear))
                    respuesta.append(caracter_de_contrasenia);
                    longitud++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("La contraseña es: %s", respuesta));
    }
}
```

En este código se comprueba cada caracter y si coincide se agrega al resultado hasta que coincida con la contraseña.

**Nota:** Este código no contempla los espacios en blanco, por ejemplo: si ingresas `1 234` te mostrará en consola: `La contraseña es: 1`.

Comment: muchas gracias !!!

Answer (score 0):

que tal comunidad muy buenas ayer no pude subir el código he estado muy ocupado con proyectos finales, sin embargo les dejo el código, estoy abierto a comentarios u observaciones
El siguiente simula el comportamiento de un algoritmo de fuerza bruta
código hecho en java.
package Ejercicios;

import java.util.*;

public class Simula_FuerzaBruta {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cadena;
    System.out.println("ingresa la cadena");
    cadena = sc.next();
    int ascii;
    char[] toCharArray = cadena.toCharArray();//descompone cadena  en char
    for (int i = 0; i < toCharArray.length; i++) {
        ascii = (int) toCharArray[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 127; j++) {
            if (j == ascii) {
                char aux=(char)ascii;//conviriendo a char 
                System.out.println("El valor de la letra en la posición " + i + " letra es " + aux);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}